# New Object from Subclass

Tags: ruby

Lets say I have two classes:

```
class House
  def initialize(width, height)
      @width = width
      @height = height
  end
end
```

and:

```
class BrickHouse < House

end
```

When I create a House:

```
house = House.new(33,22)
```

How can I create a new `Brickhouse` from this house:

**I tried:**

```
 brickhouse = BrickHouse.new(house)
```

But that didnt worked! What do I wrong? Thanks

Comment: Why not `BrickHouse.new(33, 23)`  to create a `Brickhouse` object ?

Comment: Its only a example, my real object is much more complex!

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Rails, so you should remove Rails tags. Keep in mind that some readers may filter on Rails tags (they only want to see Rails questions or they don't want to see Rails questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (when these are `ActiveRecord` objects):

```
house = House.new(33,22)
brickhouse = BrickHouse.new(house.attributes)
```

I think that should do it. Even though `House` might be very complex, `Brickhouse` should inherit those methods and now its attributes as well.

Comment: `house.attribtues` returns a `Hash`, in case you are talking about an `ActiveRecord` object, which is not stated in the question. The `initialize` method defined in the `House` class receives 2 arguments

Comment: @Fer Yeah, I was indeed thinking of an `ActiveRecord` object. It is not shown in the OP's question, so if it isn't one, this answer is incorrect and I'll remove it.

Comment: Sorry! That I didnt mentioned it, but its an `ActiveRecord`-object! Works! thanks

Answer (score 1):

The BrickHouse is inherited from House. Here the House class initialize method requires two parameters, so obviously the all subclasses should also requires two parameters.

If you want to create instance for subclass wihout passing params(specified in parent class), just make the parent class initialize params as optional like below.

```
class House
  def initialize(height = 0, weight = 0)
    @height = height
    @weight = weight
  end
end

class BrickHouse < House
end
```

Now we will be able to create instance for subclasses with the init params as zero,

```
brick_house = BrickHouse.new
```

If you pass init params that will initialize the init params

```
brick_house = BrickHouse.new(10, 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to create an instance of `Brickhouse` such that the values of its two instance variables are the same as those for `house`, that would be:

```
Brickhouse.new(house.instance_variable_get(:@width),
  house.instance_variable_get(:@height)).
```

This instance of `Brickhouse` and `house` are completely unrelated, however.

You could alternatively write: `...instance_variable_get("@width")`.